# Finding MLE of $\theta$ where $f_X(x;\theta)=1 \space \text{ or} \space \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I would like to have some input regarding my work for finding the MLE for $\theta$ for the following situation.

$X_1, ... , X_n \sim_{iid} X$ where $x\in[0,1], \space \theta=1,2$ and

$$f_X(x;\theta)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\theta=1$} \\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} & \text{if $\theta=2$}\end{cases}$$

My argument is that 
$$f_X(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}x^{1/\theta-1}$$
so using the usual process,

$$L(\theta)=\theta^{-n} \left[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right]^{1/\theta -1}$$
$$l(\theta)=-n \ln\theta+ \left(\frac{1}{\theta}-1 \right)\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i $$ 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} l(\theta)= \frac{-n}{\theta}+\frac{-1}{\theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i$$

and I want to conclude that 
$$\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i$$

What bothers me here is that $\theta$ is either $1$ or $2$, so I believe that there is something crucial that I am missing.  May I have some assistance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter space is discrete as $\theta$ takes two values $1$ and $2$. So your MLE should better be either of these values. To elaborate on the point @leonbloy makes, suppose we define a function $$I(\theta)=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }\theta=1 \\ 0&,\text{ if }\theta=2\end{cases}$$

Then the likelihood function given the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in(0,1)$ can be expressed as

$$L(\theta)=1^{I(\theta)}\left(\frac{1}{2^n \prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i}}\right)^{1-I(\theta)}\quad,\theta\in\{1,2\}$$

Clearly, $L(1)=1$ and $L(2)=\left(2^n \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i}\right)^{-1}$ for all $x_i\in(0,1)$.

So the MLE of $\theta$ must be $$\hat\theta=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }2^n \prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i}>1 \\ 2&,\text{ if }2^n \prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i}\le1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you.  Your explanation makes much more sense.

Comment: Actually, there is something that I do not understand.  How are you deciding that the statistic has to be greater than or less than or equal to 1?
My intuition tells me that if the statistic is exactly equal to 1 then $\theta =1$ but and other wise $\theta =2$.

Comment: MLE will be $1$ if $L(1)> L(2)$ and it will be $2$ if $L(1)<L(2)$. You could put an 'equal' sign in either of those two inequalities as I did but it does not matter because these are continuous variables. Equality cases occur with probability zero, so we can exclude them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $L(1)>L(2)$ implies that MLE = 1?

Comment: Really don't understand the confusion. Think about what you are doing in maximum likelihood estimation. Your MLE should be the value at which the likelihood is maximised, right?

Comment: For example, if all values of $x_i$ were to be $0.25$ then $L(1)=L(2)=1$ ?

Comment: Never mind, I was confused with the pdf being the likelihood function.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It makes absolutely no sense to find the maximum by setting the derivative to zero of the log-likelihood $l(\theta)$, because $l(\theta)$ is not a function of a continuous variable.

You are given a function $l(\theta)$ for which the variable only takes two values . Then, to find the mximum, you only need to evaluate the function in those two values  and pick the maximum.

Comment: So, I would be doing what I did if $\theta$ were to be continuous?